# How to replace a variable within a string with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, replace

So I have some PHP code that looks like:

```
$message = 'Here is the result: %s';
```

I just used %s as an example. It's basically a placeholder for whatever will go there. Then I pass the string to a function and I want that function to replace the %s with the value.

What do I need to do to achieve this? Do I need to do some regex, and use preg_replace(), or something? or is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can actually use the [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) function which will return a formatted string and will put your variables on the place of the placeholders.
It also gives you great powers over how you want your string to be formatted and displayed.

```
$output = sprintf("Here is the result: %s for this date %s", $result, $date);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use `%s`, I think that is the same placeholder that printf uses for a string. So you could do:

```
$text = sprintf($message, "replacement text");
```

Think that should work at least...

Answer (score 3):

```
$find = array(
     '#name#',
     '#date#'
);
$search = array(
     'someone\'s name',
     date("m-d-Y")
);
$text_result = str_replace($find, $search, $text);
```

I'm usually using this for my code, fetching the $text from 
some text/html files then make the $text_result as the output

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf), which works in a very similar way to C's `printf` and `sprintf` functions.

Answer (score -3):

try dynamic variables:

```
$placeholder = 's';
str_replace("%".$placeholder,$$placeholder,$message);
```

then %s will be replaced with $s, the variable