# How can I retrieve HTML/PHP code stored in a mySQL table and not have the PHP commented out?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am storing in a mySQL table the HTML/PHP content of individual slides to be displayed on a single page.

Here is an example of HTML/PHP code stored in the mySQL table:

```
<p>Welcome <?php echo $userData['fname']; ?>!</p>

<p>You made it to the first slide!</p>
```

I retrieve the content of the slides in PHP with the following code:

```
<?php 

$fetchedPageSlideData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pageSlides WHERE pageID = $pageID ORDER BY 'order' DESC") or die(mysql_error());

    while ($pageSlideData = mysql_fetch_array($fetchedPageSlideData)) {

        $pageSlideContent =  $pageSlideData['content']; ?>

        <div><?php echo $pageSlideContent; ?></div>

    <?php }

?>
```

All of the HTML of the content displays correctly, but the PHP is inserted as follows:

```
<!--?php echo $userData['fname']; ?-->
```

So the PHP is commented out and doesn't display.

How can I retrieve the HTML/PHP code and have the PHP not commented out?

Comment: What is the content of the database relevant to the code that has been inserted into the output HTML?

Comment: Stroing PHP code in database is bed pratice

Comment: @ShaktiSingh: It depends on the specific case. But yes, it **may** be incorrect in this case.

Comment: I suspect that it is the code before and after your `echo` that is causing your code to be commented out.

Comment: @Tadeck The PHP outputs the user's first name. Is that what you were asking Tadeck?

Comment: @ShaktiSingh I have read that it is a bad practice. I am still new to PHP/mySQL and don't understand why it would be bad to store something simple and seemingly harmless like `<?php echo $userData[fname]; ?>`.

Comment: @MarkRummel: No, I was asking for the actual code you store in the database, not the description of it. Sometimes the description differs from what is stored (and wee need exact value stored in the database).

Comment: @MarkRummel: Maybe because it is quite easy to change it from " _simple and seemingly harmless_ " to " _very harmful_ ". If you are new in PHP, I bet Shakti Singh is right and you should not do it. Rare cases when including PHP in the database is very useful feature are rather cases of advanced and mature software, not software written by beginners (no offense, it just needs some good foundations & well-thought-out architecture).

Comment: @Tadeck `<p>Welcome <?php echo $userData['fname']; ?>!</p> <p>You made it to the first slide!</p>`.

Comment: @MarkRummel: Ok, so the whole string " `<p>Welcome <?php echo $userData['fname']; ?>!</p> <p>You made it to the first slide!</p>` " is inserted into HTML as " `<!--?php echo $userData['fname']; ?-->` "? Please update your question with the data you have provided.

Comment: PHP and MySQL won't comment out code blocks in text strings. It'd be something else - maybe a bad sanitization function.

Comment: @Tadeck I believe I wrote it correctly above. I included the whole string I mentioned in my comment to you in my question, then in my question I said "All of the HTML of the content displays correctly, but the PHP is inserted as follows: `<!--?php echo $userData['fname']; ?-->`"

Comment: @MarcB I typed the content (`<p>Welcome <?php echo $userData['fname']; ?>!</p> <p>You made it to the first slide!</p>`) directly into mySQL with phpMyAdmin. I have called for the data with the larger bit of code in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a better idea to use placeholder strings in the DB data. Executing arbitrary php code from a DB can be dangerous. [PHP is Evil](http://www.blog.highub.com/php/php-core/php-eval-is-evil/)

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking into the use of placeholder strings. This might accomplish what I'm trying to do. Thanks again.

Comment: A good place to start:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828645/how-to-replace-a-variable-within-a-string-with-php

Answer (score 1):

Look into PHP function eval(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: Thanks. I checked out `eval()`, but it looks like it has to be within PHP, which just gets commented out.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping in and out of the PHP interpreter makes your code rather difficult to read. Consider:

```
<?php 
    $f = mysql_query(
      "SELECT * 
        FROM pageSlides 
        WHERE pageID = $pageID 
        ORDER BY 'order' DESC"
      ) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($d = mysql_fetch_array($f)) {
       print "<div>" . $d['content'] . "</div>\n";
    }
```

Regardless there is no implicit nor explicit mechanism here which would inject the comment tags you've presented. However it may be the browser trying to make sense of the **unescaped** html code and <?php ... ?> tags.

Try:

```
 print "<div>" . htmlentities($d['content']) . "</div>\n";
```

As a side note, you might consider using

```
   print "<div>" . highlight_string($d['content']) . "</div>\n";
```

Or do you mean that you actually want to run the code stored in the database - if so, you're asking for a world of pain. Eval is *not* evil - but you really must know what you're doing to avoid getting bitten by it.