# Replacing string with some variable

Tags: php, regex

I am not an expert with Regular Expression, so maybe this question has some basic implementation of regex.

First I have retrieve some string from user which has a format like this:

```
$id =3;
$format = {num}/sometext/sometext;
```

The question is how to replace `{num}` with the variable of id, so the result will be :

```
3/sometext/sometext;
```

it's kind of like a templating engine.

Comment: Obvious duplicate: [How to replace a variable within a string with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828645/how-to-replace-a-variable-within-a-string-with-php?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

```
str_replace("{num}", $id, $format);
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use `str_replace('{num}', $id, $format);` ?